# Python discord bot, command not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Why am I getting this error: `Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "Test" is not found`

I saw other posts about this but the problem was them either not having their token or the `bot.run(TOKEN)` at the bottom

*EDIT Here's the updated code, still get the same error

```
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

@bot.command()
async def on_message(ctx, arg):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return
        
    if ctx.content.startswith('hello'):
        await ctx.channel.send(arg)

bot.run(TOKEN)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Commands are case-sensitive, unless you set `case_insensitive` to True when instantiating the `Bot`

Comment: I've added the ```case_insensitive``` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

your code is basically right.
There's a "spelling" mistake in the command that you wrote in the chat.
You should use `$test` instead of `$Test` while entering the command.
However, you can avoid these mistakes by setting `case_insensitive` to `True`

With your example it would look like this:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', case_insensitive=True)
```

This should work